# submit Form in Ajax

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax

How to submit Form in Ajax in below it reload the page and display nextpage

**Controller**

```
public function ajaxcheckoutAction()
      {
          $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
          $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();

          if (array_key_exists('email', $_POST)) {
              $email = $_POST['email'];
          } else {
              $this->getResponse()->setBody(false);
              return;
          }
          if ($websiteId) {
              $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
          }
          $customer->loadByEmail($email);
          if ($customer->getId()) {
              $this->getResponse()->setBody(true);
              return;
          }
          $this->getResponse()->setBody(false);
          return;
      }
```

**Form**

```
 <form class="my-form" name="myForm" id="myForm">

    <label><h1>Get started with our login flow</h1></label>
    <div class="email-enter-field">
        <input placeholder="Email Address" type="email" name="email" id= "email" class="input-text check_custom_login" required autocomplete="on"/> 
    </div>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword') ?>" class="f-left"><?php echo $this->__('Forgot your password?') ?></a>  
    <button class="button" name="submit"/> <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></span> </button>

</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var formId = 'myForm';
    var myForm = new VarienForm(formId, true);
    var postUrl = '<?php echo $this->getUrl("ajax/index/ajaxcheckout") ?>';
    function doAjax() {
        if (myForm.validator.validate()) {
            new Ajax.Updater(
                { success:'formSuccess' }, postUrl, {
                    method:'post',
                    asynchronous:true,
                    evalScripts:false,
                    onComplete:function(request, json) {
                        Element.hide(formId);
                        Element.show('formSuccess');
                    },
                    onLoading:function(request, json){
                        Element.show('formLoader');
                    },
                    parameters: $(formId).serialize(true),
                }
            );
        }
    }

    new Event.observe(formId, 'submit', function(e){
        e.stop();
        doAjax();
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

If already register i need to show this form

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::geturl('customer/account/loginPost/')?>" method="post" id="login-form" class="Custom_checkout">

</form>
```

else this form

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::geturl('customer/account/createpost/')?>" method="post" name="fom" id="form-validate">

</form>
```

How to achieve this

Comment: Please refer to the following http://www.sagardoshi.net/blog/using-magentos-built-in-ajax-submit-with-validation.html

Comment: This will help you.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111120/ajax-form-submit-magento-redirects-to-controller-instead-processing-response

Answer (score 0):

you should have to call onclick function on submit and put this ajax function in to it

like

```
 <input id="button" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="submit" onclick="return callAjax();">
```

then in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function callAjax() {

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('ajax/index/ajaxcheckout') ?>",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {email: mail},
    success: function (exists) {
        if (exists == 0) {
            // js for fail, hide disable button etc etc
        } else if (exists == 1) {
            // js for success bits
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   // error handling
    }
});

}
</script>
```

**Edit**

we forget in new code

```
<button class="button" name="submit" type="submit"/>
```

i am sure it will work for you.

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: check my updated code

Comment: Check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code i'm using many ajax form with validation in my website magento 1.9.2 using this code for submit form with ajax.

```
<div id="contact_results"></div>        
                <form id="requestform" name="requestform" action="your_email.php" class="col-xs-12" method="post">
                    <div class="form-wrapper">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="formlabel"> Full Name </label> 
                                <input class="textfield"  data-required="true" type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="enter your name" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="formlabel"> Email </label> 
                                <input class="textfield"  data-required="true" type="email" name="email" placeholder="enter email address" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">                 
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="formlabel" for="mobile"> Phone </label>
                                <input class="phone"  data-required="true" name="phone" type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*" id="mobile" placeholder="enter phone number">
                                <input id="hidden" type="hidden" name="full_phone">
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="formlabel"> Message </label>
                                <textarea class="textfield textarea" type="textarea" placeholder="enter your message"  data-required="true" name="details"/></textarea >
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12">                 
                            <div class="field emailfunc">
                                <label class="formlabel"> What can we help you with ? </label>                      
                                <span>
                                    <input name="interested" id="logistics" value="logistics" onchange="" type="radio">
                                    <label class="inline" >Logistics</label>
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    <input name="interested" id="sales" value="sales" onchange="" type="radio">
                                    <label class="inline" >Sales</label>
                                </span>
                                <span>
                                    <input name="interested" id="customer" value="customer" onchange="" type="radio">
                                    <label class="inline" >Customer Care</label>
                                </span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="field">
                                <input class="submit" type="submit" value="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?>" name="submit">
                            </div>                      
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </form> 



<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){   

var border_color = "#C2C2C2"; //initial input border color    
jQuery("#requestform").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
    proceed = true; //set proceed flat to true

    //simple input validation
    jQuery(jQuery(this).find("input[data-required=true], textarea[data-required=true]")).each(function(){
            if(!jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
                jQuery(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
                proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
            }
            //check invalid email
            /*var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?jQuery/; 
            if(jQuery(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test(jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val()))){
                jQuery(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
                proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
            } */  
    }).on("input", function(){ //change border color to original
         jQuery(this).css('border-color', border_color);
    });

    //if everything's ok, continue with Ajax form submit
    if(proceed){ 
        var post_url = jQuery(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
        var request_method = jQuery(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
        var form_data = new FormData(this); //constructs key/value pairs representing fields and values

        jQuery.ajax({ //ajax form submit
            url : post_url,
            type: request_method,
            data : form_data,
            dataType : "json",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false
        }).done(function(res){ //fetch server "json" messages when done
            if(res.type == "error"){
                jQuery("#contact_results").html('<div class="error">'+ res.text +"</div>");
            }

            if(res.type == "done"){
                jQuery("#contact_results").html('<div class="success">'+ res.text +"</div>").show().delay(3000).fadeOut(400);
                jQuery( '#requestform' ).each(function(){
                    this.reset(1500);
                });
            }
        });
    }           
});
});
</script>
```